# Specify Route only on URL without suffix

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, url-routing

I'm using ASP.NET 4.5 and have the following routing rule in my Global.asax file:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "{*value}", "~/default.aspx")
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is redirecting dynamically generated URLs that are formatted like this:

> http://myurl.com/firstnamelastname

Here is what one might actually look like:

> http://myurl.com/davemackey

My problem is that the above redirects all requests - e.g. to axd or jpg files. Now I could add exclusions for every other type of file like so:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.axd/*pathInfo}")
```

But this would be error prone and tedious (e.g., what happens if someone adds another file type to the project?).

So, what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "{*value}(where no suffix)", "~/default.aspx")
```

Or, put into my clear English:

> If URL does not have a suffix, then redirect using defaultRoute to ~/default.aspx

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?

==

Update:

I found this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It seems that using Constraints might work to implement what I am speaking of above...but I'm not exactly sure how...

==

Update 2:

I've got a passable solution for the moment. I added the following:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{path}/{value}")
```

Since image and other files are kept in sub-directories, this forces them to be excluded. Still, I have two concerns with this

1. What if the path is longer than a single sub-directory, e.g. images/people/person.jpg?
2. What if a file is placed into the main root (shouldn't be, but it could happen) that is a jpg or etc.?

Comment: Assuming you could consider a "." as a charcter that identifies a suffix you could make a RegEx constraint to check to see if the period exists. The example constraint from the MSDN article checks to make sure locale is 2 charcters a hyphen and two charcters and that year is a 4 digit number.

Comment: And your regex for negative look-arounds is: ^((?!\.).)*$ as taken from the answer to the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word I simply changed hede to \.